# Where are eclipse preference files stored during debug?

Tags: eclipse, osgi, preferences, rcp, equinox

So I can export my RCP application and find the .pref files specific to my application under the .settings folder in my export directory.

Where are the application .prefs file stored when I run/debug the application in the eclipse IDE?  For instance I run my program from the eclipse ide and it does what's below.  Where can I find the preference file for this?

```
Preferences prefs = ConfigurationScope.INSTANCE.getNode("hostname.controllers");
    prefs.putInt("numCtrlrs", 2);
    prefs.put("ctrlr1", "adamctrlr.ohmasd.org");
    prefs.put("ctrlr2", "mnet.ohmasd.org");

    try{
        prefs.flush();
    } catch (BackingStoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

To expand on [tkotisis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/618212/tkotisis)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10198864/where-are-eclipse-preference-files-stored-during-debug/10246169#10246169), an example of the location paths would be as follows for preferences using `ConfigurationScope` and `InstanceScope`. If we use the following code in an RCP application:

```java
IEclipsePreferences sharedPreferences = ConfigurationScope.INSTANCE.getNode("ConfigurationScopeExample"); 
sharedPreferences.put("Property1", "Value1");
sharedPreferences.flush();

IEclipsePreferences workspacePreferences = InstanceScope.INSTANCE.getNode("InstanceScopeExample"); 
workspacePreferences.put("Property2", "Value2");
workspacePreferences.flush();
```

And we launch the RCP application through the IDE with the name "TestRcp.application" and workspace space "${workspace_loc}/../runtime-TestRcp.application" (seen as follows):

[image]

The respective preference files will be created/updated:

```
\{workspace}\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\TestRcp.application\.settings\ConfigurationScopeExample.prefs
    Property1=Value1
    eclipse.preferences.version=1

\runtime-TestRcp.application\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings\InstanceScopeExample.prefs
    Property2=Value2
    eclipse.preferences.version=1
```

Answer (score 1):

When running your RCP in the IDE, it is using a workspace set up in the run/debug configuration (typically named *runtime-product.name* and residing in the same path as your running Eclipse workspace).

The preference file can be found within this runtime workspace, in the corresponding path.